# AND bitwise operation over addition

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic, bitwise-and

I've been looking for a while now about this issue, yet I couldn't find any result.
assuming A, B and C are integers, is there a function (arithmetic or boolean) F and G such that:

**(A + C)&(B + C) = F(A,B) + G(C)**

where & is the bitwise operator AND.
in other word i'm looking for a way to get the C value to be independent of A and B.

**Edit**
the "+" here is the ordinary plus operation not OR.

Comment: Can you show 2 or 3 examples of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let's consider the case that A = 0, and B and C are chosen from 0 and 1. Here's the resulting table:

```
B C  output
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  0
1 1  0
```

Then we ask the question, are there functions F and G such that `F(B) + G(C) == C & (B + C)`. There can be no solution, because the first two rows imply that `G(1) = G(0) + 1` (the contribution from `F` cannot change, because its argument is zero both times), and the bottom two rows imply that `G(0) = G(1)` (again because the contribution from `F` cannot change, its argument is one both times). And we can't have it both ways, `G(1) = G(0) + 1` and `G(0) = G(1)` cannot both hold.

There are other cases than A = 0 and B and C both binary, but if F and G cannot exist in one case then all the other cases cannot "fix" that.

Comment: I understand your answer but why cant we have is both ways? G(1) = G(0) + 1 and G(0) = G(1) doesn't mean G can not exist. i think that only imply that G can be a multivalued function for example tan(pi/4)=tan(5pi/4) that doesn't mean tan() doesn't exist

Comment: @TahaKhabouss if you rearrange that a bit you can get `G(0) = G(0) + 1` and other inconsistencies